# В новых версиях python pip уже встроен и можно пользоваться python3.6 -m pip install django==1.11?

Tags: python

В новых версиях python pip уже встроен и можно пользоваться 
`python3.6 -m pip install django==1.1`1?
т.е. отдельно

```
sudo yum install python36-pip
```

можно не ставить?

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с [Python 3.4](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.4.0/) (и 2.7.9 для ветки 2.x) pip действительно входит в поставку стандартной реализации (CPython), отдельная установка не требуется.